# Redirecting an URL to new home page

Tags: redirect, iis, https, web

There is an webpage https://intranet.aimco.com/default.asp  which i want to redirect to this new URL https://aimcocom.sharepoint.com .

Please guide me how do i do it.. i cannot do it through IIS because i don't need to redirect the website .. i only need to redirect the single home page of the website. Please help me with the redirection of a webpage to another URL

Comment: When you [Googled the topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=Redirecting+an+URL+to+new+home+page), which solutions that you found have you tried?

Comment: for .asp i didnt get any solution.. i tried the IIS http redirect thing but it is redirecting the hwole website which i dont want.. i want a single page to be redirected to another URL... so that when the old wepage is hit it redirects to the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, You'll use the URL REWRITE Extension.

You can download it here:
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Once you have installed the extension and if you are having trouble creating the rule to do the re-direction. Ask a new question, on how to create the rule you're looking for using the URL Rewrite Extension in IIS. If this answer is correct, please mark it as correct.